# How do i calculate rank when i have multiple conditions in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I wanted to calculate rank of each unique username where the final score is the average of all the correct answers in various attempts by a user. Also each category should be kept different.
I saw about creating Temporary tables but the main problem is how do i write a query which would find unique usernames calculate their average and rank them.
Below is a screenshot of the Database.

[image]

Comment: if you want unique usernames, then why did you allow it in the first place? Why not have a column holding an email address instead and have that column hold a UNIQUE constraint? You should look into using relational tables also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use avg and group by

```
select username, avg(correct) 
 from my_table 
 group by username
```

of if you need  for each category

```
select username, category, avg(correct) 
 from my_table 
 group by username, category
```

Comment: to rank them you have to use ORDER BY too

Comment: It also has different categories.

Comment: answer  updated ..  ,, otherwise   updated . your question and a real data sample (not image) and the expected  result

Comment: @scaisEdge Done! I tried earlier too but it showed you've got to wait some time before marking as correct.